# If $a+b+c=3$ Prove that $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\geq\frac{2+a}{2+b}+\frac{2+b}{2+c}+\frac{2+c}{2+a}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

**Question** -

> Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=3 .$ Prove that
>   $$
> a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \geq \frac{2+a}{2+b}+\frac{2+b}{2+c}+\frac{2+c}{2+a}
> $$

**My try** -

i tried putting $a+2 = x, b+2=y , c+2=z$

then we get $x+y+z=9$ and after simplification we have to prove that

$3>x/y + y/z + z/x$ which i am not able to prove...

i also tried C-S,Chebyshev,rearrangement..etc but none of them working

any hints ???

thankyou

Comment: By the AM-GM inequality we have
$$\frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{y}\frac{y}{z}\frac{z}{x}} =1$$
which yields the opposite of what you claim. Consider showing the steps of your "simplification"

Comment: no,i did not expand ,i used Root mean square on LHS of your first inequality...but yeah it cannot be done because we have already shown reverse inequality so this approach  is wrong...can anyone solve it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way.  Notice that
$$\frac{2+a}{2+b} = \frac{5a+2b+2c}{2a+5b+2c} = \frac52 -\frac32\cdot\frac{7b+2c}{2a+5b+2c} $$

Also using CS inequality ($\sum $ representing cyclic sums):
$$\sum \frac{7b+2c}{2a+5b+2c} \geqslant \frac{\left( \sum (7b+2c)\right)^2}{\sum (7b+2c)(2a+5b+2c)}= \frac{81(a+b+c)^2}{18\sum a^2+21(a+b+c)^2} \\= \frac{729}{18\sum a^2+189}$$

By the above bound, with $x = \sum a^2 \geqslant 3$, it is enough to show 
$$x \geqslant \frac{15}2- \frac32\cdot\frac{729}{18x + 189} \iff \frac{2(x+6)(x-3)}{2x+21}\geqslant 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2-\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}\geq\frac{2+a}{2+b}+\frac{2+b}{2+a}-2+\frac{2+b}{2+c}-\frac{2+b}{2+a}+\frac{2+c}{2+a}-1$$ or
$$\frac{2}{3}((a-b)^2+(c-a)(c-b))\geq\frac{(a-b)^2}{(2+a)(2+b)}+\frac{(c-a)(c-b)}{(2+a)(2+c)},$$ which is true because
$$\frac{2}{3}>\frac{1}{4}>\frac{1}{(2+a)(2+b)}$$ and
$$\frac{2}{3}>\frac{1}{(2+a)(2+c)}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I see, but how $\frac{2}{3}>\frac{1}{4}>\frac{1}{(2+a)(2+b)}$? Thank you!

Comment: @tthnew Because $(2+a)(2+b)=4+2(a+b)+ab>4.$

Comment: thanks,Michael but is there a proof that uses know inequalities like C-S,chebyshev,holder,...etc ???

Comment: because thinking of factorization like this is bit hard for me...

Comment: @User88463 But I think my solution is very easy. Ask your questions. For example: $\frac{2}{3}>\frac{1}{4}$. Is it clear? If so, all steps in my solution are in the same level.

Comment: i am not saying your solution is tough, i am saying thinking of such a factorization is quite hard...anyway thanks